# App crash after startActivity start

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to switch between two activity and I put an if statement, but after I resolve the startActivity method the app crashes:

**activity1.java**

```
public class StartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int count =0;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Context context = this;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

        db=openOrCreateDatabase("StopSmokeDB", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);

        try {
             Cursor mCount = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from UserTable", null);
             mCount.moveToFirst();
             count= mCount.getInt(0);
         } catch (Exception e){
         } finally {
             if(count > 0){
                 finish();
                 Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
             } else {
                 finish();
                 startActivity(new Intent(this,RegActivity.class));
             }
         }
      }
}
```

**androidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="tzahianidgar.stopsmoke.RegActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="tzahianidgar.stopsmoke.StartActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

this is my logcat:
04-10 05:57:38.316 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-10 05:57:38.602 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke-1/lib/x86
04-10 05:57:38.733 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke-1/lib/x86

Comment: What is the crash? Supply the error message and stack trace

Comment: Look in the logcat. Android will tell you something about why your app crashed.

Comment: 08:51:40 Executing tasks: [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex]
08:51:44 Gradle build finished in 3s 480ms
08:51:45 No changes to deploy
         (Don't show again)

Comment: this is my event log

Comment: This is your compilation log! I'm asking about your logcat

Comment: 04-10 05:57:38.316 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
04-10 05:57:38.602 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke-1/lib/x86
04-10 05:57:38.733 3630-3630/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/tzahianidgar.stopsmoke-1/lib/x86

Comment: First of all, edit your post, it's harder to read stack traces in comments. Second, you've supplied `I` and `W` levels, but no `E`... the crash reason would be at `E` level. Also, check the `AndroidRuntime` tag.

Comment: Can you be more specific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108734/discussion-between-tzahi-and-ori-lentz).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should close the Cursor after using like:

```
if(mCount != null)
   mCount.close();
```

Secondly, You closed your current activity before starting a new one. Replace your finally block code with this:

```
finally {
         if(mCount != null)
             mCount.close();

         if(count > 0){
             startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
             finish();
         } else {
             startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this,RegActivity.class));
             finish();
         }
     }
```